# Worksheet function for conditional test of the direction of change in most recent period

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, worksheet-function

I have data in 4 columns as below:

```
A      B      C      D
10     12     9      9
25     22 
11     11     11
11     10     18     19
18     18     18
21     22     18
```

The column heads are:

```
A:1st visit
B: 2nd visit
C: 3rd Visit
D: 4th Visit
```

Now in column F the result should be this:

- if the most recent visit score increased on the previous visit, column F should show "Inc"
- if the most recent visit score decreased on the previous visit, column F should show "Dec"
- if the most recent visit score is unchanged from the previous visit, column F should show "Stbl"

To be clear, if `B2` has data then it should be compared to `A2`.

If `C2` has data then it should be compared to `B2`. No need to check for `A2` data.

If `D2` has data then is should be compared to `C2`. No need compare with `B2` and `A2`.

What should be formula for this? In linux os.

Comment: What do you mean by ANY VISIT? Which cells should be compared? Can you post the expected answer of the F cell for each of the rows?

Comment: What if a row increases in one step then decreases in another?

Comment: @Nisha the excepted answer F cell is as follows: stbl , stbl, stbl, inc, stbl, dec

Comment: Why is the second row expected to be stable? The last change is 25 > 22 so it shouldn't it be decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've asked for and test if the last change was an increase, decrease or unchanged.

```
=IF(INDEX(OFFSET(B2,,,,COUNT(A2:D2))-OFFSET(A2,,,,COUNT(A2:D2)),,COUNT(A2:D2)-1) > 0, "Inc",IF(INDEX((OFFSET(B2,,,,COUNT(A2:D2))-OFFSET(A2,,,,COUNT(A2:D2))),,COUNT(A2:D2)-1)<0,"Dec","Stbl"))
```

Copy this into `F2`, confirm it as an array formula with `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`, then drag it down the column.

For your sample data it gives the following results:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
10  12  9   9       Stbl
25  22              Dec
11  11  11          Stbl
11  10  18  19      Inc
18  18  18          Stbl
21  22  18          Dec
```

It works by creating an array of column-to-column changes, then testing the second from last value in that array to see if it is >0, <0, or unchanged.

Comment: first it should compare D1 with C1 id D1 increase than c1 then "inc" eles "dec" n if the both data same then "stbl"
if there is no data in D1 then it shd compare with  B1 of C1 data             
if there is no data in C1 then is should compare with A1 of B1 data
if there is no data in B1 then F1 should be blank

Comment: Edited answer. Let me know if this is what you're looking for since the output isn't the same as you say is expected in your comment under the question.

Comment: Thanks @ Jamie Bull. It's working but if there is no value in B C D the data is only A that case the result shd be Blank 
also you are correct 2nd row should be "Dec" it was my typo error

Comment: Thanks This is working but two errors 
1. when data is only in A column then Result should be Blank
2. I have applied the formula till end of row (2000) but my data is up to Row 685 .. after that is shows #REF.. so need to correct I try to insert the Iserror & Isblank function but it s not working 

please help me

Comment: You can wrap the whole thing up in `=iferror(if(A2="","Blank",...),"")`

Comment: Thanks for answer Jamie. .it had worked properly. .but recently I hv changed my system which has linux os. This above command s not working. Shows error. Please provide me solutions

Answer (score 0):

*Changed to reflect edit to OP and pedantic interpretation of a further comment.*

Because of `than the previous visit` I think a single column output may not be sufficient, so suggest, if `25` is in A3, in G2 and copied to G2:I7:

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(B2=A2,"stbl",MATCH(MAX($A2:B2),$A2:B2,0)-MATCH(MIN($A2:B2),$A2:B2,0)))
```

and in F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ROW()=3,"stbl",IF(CELL("contents",I2)<>"",I2,IF(CELL("contents",H2)<>"",H2,IF(CELL("contents",G2)<>"",G2,""))))
```

copied across to suit, with custom formatting of the results of:

```
"inc";"dec";"stbl"
```

Thus:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. .it had worked properly. .but recently I hv changed my system which has linux os. This above command s not working. Shows error. Please provide me solutions